# kotlin,How value of Actual variable we can change in another class to which it passed using parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Delegation in Kotlin. So therefore I have base class which handles common network result but only difference is Data(Model class)

```
class BaseDataDelegation<T>(var oldData: T): WebDataListener<T> {
    override fun onSuccess(data: T) {
        oldData = data //oldData's original variable value which is inside main activity should also be updated

               /.../
    }

    override fun onFailed() {
      /.../
    }


}
```

then In MainActivity I'm calling

```
dataManager.getResponse(BaseDataDelegation(oldData))//in DataManager.getResponse(listener:WebDataListener<T>)
```

Now as I passed `oldData` to `BaseDataDelegation`, so when value of `oldData` is changed in `BaseDataDelegation` class it should reflect back to variable of `MainActivty`.
How can I do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mutable [property reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#property-references) to achieve this. Here's an example:

```
class BaseDelegation<T>(val property: KMutableProperty0<T>) {
    override fun onSuccess(data: T) {
        property.set(data)
    }
}
```

Then, to construct a `BaseDelegation`, use a [bound reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11) to a property, e.g. `this::oldData` or `myActivity::oldData` (the property itself should be mutable, i.e. `var`).

Here's a simplified runnable demo: [(link)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/nmdf0hc73jrua64b4pk8gds2op/m3rcqmlf7p6s4jd4gid7b96i7g)

Comment: looks like it will work , i will  update you  after implementing it .

Comment: first of all thanks it is working but I don't understand much about it that how it is working,i have read documentation but not very helpful , can you please explain more